# ROBLOX Studio: How do I run this Lua Bytecode VM?

Tags: lua

For me, I want to learn how VM's work and if they can only be ran on Mac. I've found a bytecode vm (from lua) in roblox studio as one of the scripts. I'm very confused on how to use it, its nothing like i've used before. Here it is:

https://web.roblox.com/library/117513593/EpicLua-Lua-5-1-VM

Also if you could tell me more about VM's that would also help me during this process.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's plug-and-play.
Require the module in a script/command line on Roblox. It will return a function which you can call with a string and desired environment (optional), which again returns a function you can run to run the string-code.

Example:

```
local LoadString = require(module)
local func = LoadString("print('Hello world!')")
func() -- prints "Hello world!"
```

Comment: How do you make it so that you can compile the script into a bytecode? I'm into more of a script obfuscation/encryption. Like for example, print("test") would turn into https://hastebin.com/raw/vayewopeda (which does work)